# Suppress output unless non-zero exit code

Tags: shell-script, cron, io-redirection

What's the best way to suppress output (stdout and stderr) unless the program exits with a non-zero code?  I'm thinking:

```
quiet_success()
{
  file=$(mktemp)
  if ! "$@" > "$file" 2>&1; then
    cat "$file"
  fi
  rm -f "$file"
}
```

And run `quiet_success my_long_noisy_script.sh` but I'm not sure if there's a better way.  I feel like this has to be something other people have needed to do.

For context, I'm looking to add this to my cron scripts so that I get emailed with everything if they fail, but not if they don't.

Comment: This should be the default behavior of most commands (no output on success).  If not, the first thing to do is to look for an option / switch to enable such behavior.  Failing that, your approach is the right idea.  Side note: I'm assuming you posted pseudo-code because it is not actually valid `sh` syntax, and your redirection order is backwards (do `> "$file" 2>&1` and use more quotes).

Comment: Yep, I just typed it up in the question.  Applied your suggestion, and I agree, the command *should* be responsible for that, but alas...

Comment: Just a syntax note: no need for parenthesis around the command.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're going to have to buffer the output somewhere no matter what, since you need to wait for the exit code to know what to do. Something like this is probably easiest:

```
$ output=`my_long_noisy_script.sh 2>&1` || echo $output
```

Comment: Note that if you use `set -o xtrace` in your shell script then all the output will be there again as part of logging the details of the assignment `output=...` :-). In that case it's probably better to use `chronic`.

Answer (score 12):

The [`moreutils`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/moreutils) package contains a program [`chronic`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/chronic.1.html) for this purpose. You just call it like

```
chronic my_program args ...
```

Very handy in cron jobs.

Comment: Do not be like me and mistake `chronic` for `cronic`, which is a similar program that suppresses output unless a command exists with a non-zero code *or produces standard error output*.