# How can I suppress output only if the command succeeds?

Tags: scripting, error-handling

I would like to simplify the output of a script by suppressing the output of secondary commands that are usually successful.

However, using `-q` on them hides the output when they occasionally fail, so I have no way of understanding the error. Additionally, these commands log their output on `stderr`.

Is there a way to suppress a command's output **only if it succeeds**?

For example (but not limited to) something like this:

```
mycommand | fingerscrossed
```

If all goes well, `fingerscrossed` catches the output and discards it. Else it echoes it to the standard or error output (whatever).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just found this much simpler answer on [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41381/suppress-output-unless-non-zero-exit-code):

```
output=`mycommand 2>&1` || echo $output
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: Note: for my use case this was a much simpler solution (avoid installing extra stuff on all CI servers) so I chose to mark this one as accepted. YMMV.

Comment: Note that if you use set -o xtrace in your shell script then all the output will be there again as part of logging the details of the assignment output=... :-). In that case it's probably better to use chronic.

Comment: One IMPORTANT difference from chronic -- if your script exits on failure (ala `set -e`) - chronic returns false, and execution will stop. If you want your simpler version to also stop, it needs: `(echo $output && false)`

Comment: `2>&1` is the key!

Comment: This _almost_ works perfectly, but it will suppress newlines from the result. (Or, at least, does for me.)

Answer (score 45):

[`moreutils`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)' `chronic` command does just that:

```
chronic mycommand
```

will swallow `mycommand`'s output, unless it fails, in which case the output is displayed.

Comment: Thank you. I take it it's not installed by default on most Unix OSes?

Comment: Probably not, although it's widely packaged so it should be easy to install.

Comment: Debian has it in package `moreutils`. Nice for me, anyway :)

Comment: Note that it stores the whole output in memory.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas that's likely the only way to implement something like this, the output needs to be stored while the command is running in case it is needed.

Comment: @Dave it could be stored in a file somewhere (as in mikeserv's answer).

Comment: @StephenKitt fair enough, the difference of a temp file vs memory, depending on output size both have their benefits

Comment: If there's enough output that storing in memory is an issue, shouldn't you be writing it to a file anyway given that most terminal emulators have a limit on how far back they'll allow you to go (and plain terminals usually require piping to a pager)?

Answer (score 12):

```sh
### do this bit once at the top of your script
divert=
exec 3<>"${divert:=$(mktmp)}" 4<>/dev/null
rm -- "$divert"; unset divert
### then do this bit as often as needed
command >&3 2>&3
cat <&3 >&"$(((RTN=$?)?2:4))"
```

That should probably do the trick. It will buffer the output of each *`command`* into a deleted temporary file, and afterward siphon its output into either `/dev/null` or stderr depending on whether or not its return status was not zero. Because the temp file is deleted ahead of time it cannot be read by any process but the current shell and its children on its file descriptor *(barring sneaky `/proc/$pid/fd` snoops with appropriate permissions)*, and it does not require cleaning up when you're through.

Perhaps a more convenient solution on linux systems:

```sh
divert(){
    "$@" >&3 2>&3 ||
    eval "cat <&3
          return $?"
}   3<<"" 3<>/dev/fd/3
```

... which, in most shells, works much like the other, except that you can call it like: `divert some simple-command with args`. Beware of high output commands in `"$@"`, though for `dash`, `yash`, or some other shells which do here-documents with pipes - I think it may be possible in those shells to fill the pipe buffer *(at a default of around 128kb on linuxes)* and so deadlock. That shouldn't be a worry for `ksh`, `mksh`, `bash`, `zsh`, or the Bourne shell, though - all of those do basically the same thing as I did explicitly above with `exec`.

Answer (score 11):

Usually in case of error the command outputs messages to `stderr` so for you task you can just supress `stdout`

```
mycommand > /dev/null
```

Comment: [Be careful](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-VHkETr8YmO0/Uy01sQV6smI/AAAAAAAAYL8/jQauPTn5luQ/w506-h504/dev.png)

Comment: Thank you, but as I said in the question my commands log all the output on `stderr` (so it has no effect).

Answer (score 5):

To make your own chronic

```
my_chronic() {
  tmp=$(mktemp) || return # this will be the temp file w/ the output
  "$@"  > "$tmp" 2>&1 # this should run the command, respecting all arguments
  ret=$?
  [ "$ret" -eq 0 ] || cat "$tmp"  # if $? (the return of the last run command) is not zero, cat the temp file
  rm -f "$tmp"
  return "$ret" # return the exit status of the command
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I do something like this in my makefiles:

```
if (mycommand) &> mycommand.log; then 
  echo success 
else 
  c=$?; 
  echo;echo -e "Bad result from previous command, see mycommand.log for more details";echo;
  command_to_run_on_fail
  (exit $c)
fi
```

Adapting that to your situation, you could do something like this:

```
if ! (mycommand) &> mycommand.log; then 
  c=$?; 
  cat mycommand.log
  rm mycommand.log
  (exit $c)
fi
```

So, "if" runs the command and pipes the output to mycommand.log. If you need to catch stdout vs stdout vs whatever, you may need to change the pipe command '&>' to '>'. If the command fails then capture the error code, print out the contents of mycommand.log, remove mycommand.log, and finally return with the original error code.

Without the (exit $c) you would return with the exit code that matches the what the 'rm' command returned.

Finally, if you want a one liner, something like this would work.

```
mycommand &> mycommand.log || cat mycommand.log; rm mycommand.log
```

Comment: Do you really wrap your commands/etc. in `(...)` like that? Because it doesn't do anything useful for you but spawn extra sub-shells.

Comment: @EtanReisner `(exit $c)` is setting `$?`, which is something you can't do otherwise. `if ! (mycommand) &>x` is meaningful with the redirection if the command uses e.g. `time` or would give a shell error.

Comment: @MichaelHomer - for those things there are `{ ; }` the curlies... though `exit` is a little tricky there, admittedly.

Comment: In a makefile snippet if you are trying to exit with the previously saved `$?` then you can just use `exit $c` but yes, in other cases `(exit $?)` has value (though a shell function `rret() { return $1; }` would be better in general I'd argue). The subshell for commands still doesn't really though as mikeserv indicated.