# How might I only write stdout to file if exit code is 0?

Tags: pipe, stdin, exit-status

The [sponge](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/moreutils/sponge.1.en.html) command "soak[s] up standard input and write[s] to a file", which lets us pipe from and to the same file. I want to do something similar, where I pipe to a sponge-like utility, but if the source command fails (has a non-zero exit), I would like that sponge-like utility to leave the destination file unchanged.

Something along the lines of:

```bash
cue export package.cue | prettier --stdin-filepath .json
 | spongelike --abort-on-non-zero package.json
```

(I know I can and have rewritten this particular pipe as two separate commands, but I can see this being useful in other trickier scenarios.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I suppress output only if the command succeeds?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256120/how-can-i-suppress-output-only-if-the-command-succeeds)

Comment: This is essentially just having to invert the exit code with the answers of the dupe (e.g., with the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256487/70524): `output=$(cue export package.cue | prettier --stdin-filepath .json) && printf "%s\n" "$output" > some-file` - `&&` instead of `||`. Or wrap the command in `sh -c` and use that to invert the exit status with the other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `cmd1 | cmd2`, `cmd1`  and `cmd2` are started concurrently and are both children of the shell.

`cmd2` can't know when `cmd1` dies nor get its exit status. Only the parent (here the shell) can.

So if there's a command that does what you want, it could not be invoked as:

```
cmd | that-command output-file
```

It would have to be:

```
that-command output-file cmd
```

Where `that-command` starts `cmd` in a child process, collects its standard output via a pipe and/or stores it somewhere (memory or  temp file), waits for the child and if that succeeds, opens  `output-file` and dumps the saved output there.

That could be done with a shell script such as:

```
#! /bin/sh -
usage() {
  printf >&2 'Usage: %s <output> <cmd> [<args>...]\n' "${0##*/}"
  exit 1
}
[ "$#" -ge 2 ] || usage
output=$1; shift

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit
exec > "$tmp" 3< "$tmp"
rm -f -- "$tmp" || exit

"$@" 3<&- && cat <&3 3<&- > "$output"
```

(`mktemp` not standard yet, but very common).

Here used as:

```
cue export package.cue | that-script package.json prettier --stdin-filepath .json
```

Or, to check that both `cue` and `prettier` succeed:

```
that-script package.json ksh -o pipefail -c '
  cue export package.cue | prettier --stdin-filepath .json'
```

Or any other shell that is installed and supports that `pipefail` option from ksh (includes zsh, bash, mksh, yash at least). That option will be in the next version of the POSIX standard, so your `sh` may already have it, in which case, you could also do:

```
that-script package.json eval 'set -o pipefail
  cue export package.cue | prettier --stdin-filepath .json'
```

Beware the code run in that `eval` statement can have an influence on how the output file is created. For instance, with `that-script output eval 'cd /some/dir; cmd'`, the output file will be created in `/some/dir`, and you can use `that-script output eval 'umask 077; set -o noclobber; cmd'` to set umask and prevent clobbering.

Comment: I love it! Let's get this into moreutils stat! ;)